# How to Extract a file/Document name from Encoded Absolute URL/Server Realtive URL in SPD workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I have a URL of a document/File from One of my Document library so from that URL I want to get the only name of that specific document/file.
I have server relative URL like
**sites/appdev/MyLibrary/Doc.png**
and I want to get only **Doc.png**
how can I get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store Name of document by using **[Current Item : Name]**  in a variable. 
**OR**
**1.** Use action `Set workflow varible` to store the string. (e.g. string =   sites/appdev/MyLibrary/Doc.png)
**2.** `Find MyLibrary in string (Output to Variable: index)`
   Index contains the result, which would be number 14.
**3.** `Copy 14 characters from end of string (Output to Variable: substring)`
   This will return `MyLibrary/Doc.png`.
**4.** `Find / in substring (Output to Variable: index1)`
   Index1 contains the result, which would be number 10.
**5.** `Copy from substring, starting at 10 (Output to Variable: substring1)`
   substring1: **Doc.png**

Reference:
http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sharepoint-2013/sharepoint-designer-workflow-string-actions.htm